# Как сделать две реализации шаблонной функции при помощи SFINAE? C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, sfinae

Есть функция, которая принимает лямбду. Я через SFINAE проверяю ее на возможность вызова с определенными типами аргументов. Если это невозможно, то шаблон отбрасывается:

```
    template
    <
        typename Func,
        typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func, Pixel<PIXEL_TYPE>&, const int[]>>
    >
    void for_each(cv::Mat& img, Func&& callback) const {
    
        // реализация

    }
```

Все прекрасно работает, но я хочу сделать еще вторую реализацию функции, которая принимает лямбду с аргументом не Pixel<PIXEL_TYPE>, а просто PIXEL_TYPE. Я попытался сделать так:

```
    template
    <
        typename Func,
        typename = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Func, PIXEL_TYPE&, const int[]>>
    >
    void for_each(cv::Mat& img, Func&& callback) const {

        // другая реализация

    }
```

Естественно мне выбило ошибку, что функция уже объявлена. Как мне реализовать подобный механизм и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы заметили, шаблонные аргументы по умолчанию не учитываются при проверке функций на одинаковость.

Зато типы шаблонных параметров учитываются. Вместо `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` используйте:

```
std::enable_if_t<..., std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
```

Также этот способ лучше тем, что проверку невозможно отключить, передав свой аргумент в этот параметр.

Тип здесь не обязан быть `std::nullptr_t`, можно взять какой-нибудь `int`. Но `std::nullptr_t` хорош тем, что у него только одно возможное значение, поэтому криворукий пользователь не сможет случайно инстанцировать ваш шаблон больше одного раза, передав разные аргументы в этот параметр.

---

В C++20 вместо SFINAE проще использовать `requires`:

```
template <typename Func> requires std::is_invocable_v<...>
```

Или, еще лучше, концепт `std::invocable`:

```
template <std::invocable<Pixel<PIXEL_TYPE>&, const int[]> Func>
```